# How can I change the default New Project directory in Godot Engine?

Tags: godot

When I go to create a new project in Godot Engine (version 3.2) my Project Path is always the original default directory, no matter what path I last used. There doesn't appear to be any configuration inside the Project List window. How can I change the default project path for new projects?

[image: the create new project dialog, with the project path highlighted]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This setting is inside the project editor, so you'll first need to create or open a project. Then:

1. From the toolbar, open Editor Settings

[image]

2. In the sidebar of Editor Settings, go to Filesystem → Directories. From there you'll be able to set the **Default Project Path** to whatever you'd like:

[image]

Comment: *cough* acceptable answer :)

Comment: @Pikalek hint taken :D